# Highstocks ordinal xAxis formatting

Tags: highcharts

My case: Plot a stockchart with stock data for 5 days without weekends displaying, each day should have equal space even though data can be irregular.

What i need to do is plot an xAxis with static intervals of one day, however i cant display weekends and the data can be very irregular between the days. I've tried tinkering with tickInterval, tickPositioner but so far no luck.

I can hide weekends with:

```
ordinal: true,
```

My current fiddle: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/svedino/h9448fk0/1/

Setting the ordinal to false gives me correct interval but with the weekends included.

An example of this kind of graph seems to be working can be found here: 
    https://www.avanza.se/aktier/om-aktien.html/229675/jays

Comment: So from one side you want to use ordinal axis (to hide weekend), but you don't want to have ordinal for the rest of week? There is only one option for ordinal, so it can be easily done. I see two possible workarounds: use separate series for week days without weekends which will have all points for all days (with `null` values to hide points) - that will create regular interval in days. Second one is to play around with [`gapSize`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.gapSize). Of course, you can always edit source code but I don't count this as solution/workaround..

Comment: I solved this issue by creating a new series which contains data for every minute the previous five stock days from 09.00-17.30. Then I hid that series and removed mousetracking. This created the layout I wanted! :)

Comment: So, it's first solution suggested in my comment :) Good job!